# angularjs stops working whenever I name the ngapp or try using a controller

Tags: angularjs

I am starting to learn AngularJS and wanted to try building a simple calculator app, however, whenever I name the ng-app in my html-file, AngularJS stops working.

I tried building a controller, but seem to be doing something wrong when calling it or putting it to use.

I tried putting the files in the XAMPP webfolder because I thought it might not load from my hard drive, but to no avail.

(please disregard all the half-finished rest, right now I just want to get the controller working)

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Calculator</title>

</head>

<body ng-app="calculatorApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="first" autofocus>
    <input type="number" ng-model="second">
    <br>
    <button onClick="defineOperator('+')">+</button>
    <button onClick="defineOperator('-')">-</button>
    <button onClick="test()">TEST</button>
    <br>
    <div>
  {{first}}
</div>
</div> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"</script>
<script src="http://localhost/calculator/scripts/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the js:

```
angular.module('calculatorApp', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.defineOperator = function(choice) {
      switch (operator) {
        case +:
        return first + second;

          break;
        default:

      }
    };
    $scope.testOperator = function(click) {
      alert("You chose " + operator);
    };
  });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('calculatorApp', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.first="hello";
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Calculator</title>

</head>

<body ng-app="calculatorApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
 
<div>
  {{first}}
</div>
</div> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Have a look at this. One thing you have not closed the  tag in which angular is defined.

Comment: One more thing I suggest that try to put the angular script file in head tag(if you are learning ).

Comment: Thanks you for your help! Though in the AngularJS course on treehouse which I did the said to put all the scripts at the end of the body tag. Your suggestion does seem more orderly to me ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. We include it at last as the script should load at last. but I used it at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"</script>
```

You forgot to put `>` in above line.

Replace it with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to end the script tag with >

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to change the app-name in html page you should also change the app name in the js file :

```
angular.module('calculatorApp', [])
```